# Adding a nonce to a form that was manually created

Tags: web2py

Is there a way to add a nonce to a manually created form? For example, creating an SQLFORM in the controller and rendering it as `{{=form}}` in the views will automatically attach the nonce to the form.

But something manually created like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Won't have the nonce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct and process the form object in the controller as usual using `FORM()` or `SQLFORM()`. In that case, you can still create completely custom HTML for the form in the view (as long as the input field names match) -- you just have to include the special hidden _formname and _formkey fields, which you can do via `form.custom.end`.

In the controller:

```
def myform():
    return dict(form=SQLFORM(db.mytable).process())
```

In the view:

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
{{=form.custom.end}}
```

Note, `form.custom.end` includes the closing `</form>` tag, so no need to add that explicitly.

If you want the HTML to be more explicit, you can also access the _formname and _formkey values via `form.formname` and `form.formkey`, so you could do:

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input name="_formkey" type="hidden" value="{{=form.formkey}}" />\
        <input name="_formname" type="hidden" value="{{=form.formname}}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This produces the same HTML as the version above using `form.custom.end`.

Note, web2py stores the _formkey value in the session using the _formname as the key to retrieve it from the session. When the form is submitted, the `.process()` method retrieves the _formkey value from the session and checks that it matches the _formkey value submitted with the form -- if not, processing fails.

Finally, if you really just want to create your own custom formkey and handle storing it in the session and comparing it to the value submitted with the form yourself, you can do:

```
from gluon.utils import web2py_uuid()
custom_formkey = web2py_uuid()
```

You would then have to handle the formkey check explicitly.

Comment: For a simple form `form=FORM(INPUT(_type="submit"))`, the [docs here](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07) returns `return dict(form=form)` and when rendered `{{=form}}`, I don't see the hidden nonce inputs. But when I do (as you suggested) `return dict(form=form.process())`, the nonce appears as hidden on the form. Does the docs need to be updated or am I missing something?

Comment: No, the docs are correct. Calling `form.process()` does validation and creates/checks the formkey (and does a database insert if it is a SQLFORM). If you don't want validation or the formkey check, then there is no need to call `.process()`. The example you cite is just the first basic example of using the `FORM` helper. Immediately after that it says, "Now we add one level of complexity by adding form validation and processing," at which point the `.accepts()` method is introduced (and then `.validate()` and `.process()`, which are shortcuts for `.accepts()`).